# 26 thousand users of Facebook list their location as Greenland

Tags: sociology, social-media, facebook

Recently, according to [this](http://www.checkfacebook.com/) map 25 680 users of Facebook list their location as Greenland. 26 000 is about half of the number of inhabitants of [Greenland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenland). If these data are reliable it says that there are 26 000 computers (or other devices with IP address) from which a Facebook account was created. At least I hope that the extreme that all the accounts were created from a few computers, does not hold.

Is it possible for Greenland to have reliable Internet infrastructure? What types of networks are there (optic, cable, wireless, satellite)? What special problems have they to solve (cold, snowstorm, bad visibility) to have good connection?

(maybe not suitable question for *skeptics* now, please suggest moving to other SE site)

Comment: some might be fake or double accounts

Comment: There is the actual claim which is Facebook has 25k+ accounts that list their location as greenland.  Then there is the implication which would be that there are 25k+ people using facebook in greenland.  However there is no actual claim that this is true.  You need to either find a claim that the vast majority of accounts claiming Greenland are accurate or change the question to address the claim you do have.

Comment: Where do you get the claim that the accounts were created from Greenland.  I believe you can choose your country in Facebook.

Comment: @Chad This would be interesting solution if you would proof that in Greenland such number of accounts wasn't created and most of the users created it abroad. But has it sense to create an account and don't use it? Or they created it because they are proud that they are from Greenland?

Comment: @xralf - Skeptics is about investigating notable claims.  There is not one here.

Comment: This is a pretty boring question, running cables to Greenland isn't that impressive, we have [transatlantic cables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transatlantic_telecommunications_cable) and they have existed for over 150 years.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In 2009 Greenland had [52,000 internet](http://www.internetworldstats.com/am/gl.htm) users, which are over 90% of the population. Greenland is [connected via fiber-optic](http://www.telepost.gl/en-US/GreenlandConnect/Soekablet/Sider/Teknologi.aspx) to Canada and Iceland.

Now, is 45-50% reach in case Facebook accounts something impressive? It isn't. Facebook's global average [reach of **active** users is 44.5%](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/facebook.com#reach).

> What special problems have they to solve (cold, snowstorm, bad
>   visibility) to have good connection?

In Greenland there are [no inland settlements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_and_towns_in_Greenland), most of the population lives in the towns on the south-west coast.

> [...] according to [this](http://www.checkfacebook.com/) map [...] If these data are reliable

That's another issue. I don't think this map is reliable, as it shows many countries with FB usage way over 100% (with cases as extreme as 619% in Central African Republic or 505% in Iraq).

Comment: Well there are a lot of billionaires that die heir-less in central Africa... I am sure that accounts for the extra accounts...

Comment: Thank you for great answer it seems that all people live in the area where are good conditions. I haven't noticed numbers more than 100 %, there do you see it?

Comment: @xralf: go to "% of the population" tab, then click some country (like eg. Iraq), you'll see details in sidebar on the right.

Comment: @vartec I haven't noticed these errors :-) Good finding.